# Theming Bootsrap 4 - Color-yiq as a variable override

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, sass, bootstrap-4, theming

I want to override bootstrap variables but using the color-yiq function, for example:

```
$body-bg:     $black;
$body-color:  color-yiq($body-bg);
```

This is the SCSS structure

```
 // Overrides variables from all sources
@import "variables";

// Bootstrap
@import "../../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap";

// Fonts
@import "../../node_modules/font-awesome/scss/font-awesome";
@import "../../node_modules/material-design-icons-iconfont/src/material-design-icons";

// Plugins
@import "../../node_modules/datatables.net-bs4/css/dataTables.bootstrap4";

// André's Core - Bootstrap improvments
@import "core";
```

The CSS output is this:

```
body {
   color: color-yiq(#000);
   text-align: left;
   background-color: #000;
}
```

Using other fuctions like darken or lighten works except for color-yiq, any help?

Thanks!

Comment: This works https://www.codeply.com/go/g4LFfVEaIB

Comment: Thank you for your anwser, I didn't want to do that, (I did it before) I just copied the function and put it at the start of my "variables" before bootstrap

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to import _functions like this:

`@import "node_modules/bootstrap/scss/_functions.scss";`

And don't forget to declare (before) the needed variables. As an example:

```
$yiq-text-dark: black !default;
$yiq-text-light: white !default;
$yiq-contrasted-threshold: 150 !default;
```